# Installing turbogears 2.1 on Windows 7 x86 error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, windows, pip, turbogears

I created enviroment in C:\Projects2010\Python\Environments:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe myenv
```

Then ran activate.bat:

```
C:\Projects2010\Python\Environments\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Then ran pip:

```
C:\Projects2010\Python\Environments\myenv\Scripts\pip.exe install -i http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/downloads/current/index tg.devtools
```

and got error "The system cannot find the file specified".

Log is [there](http://pastebin.com/S125GjVv).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such "build" errors, it is best to use a *[binary](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/tg.devtools/)* package manager

1. Install [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) (32-bit)
2. Type `pypm -E C:\Projects2010\Python\Environments\myenv install tg.devtools`